# Turtle run away

Tags: netlogo

I am testing NetLogo, I am assembling two models Halo and Fire, what I would like to do is when the fire touches the halo of a turtle the turtle runs away and warns other turtles not to go to the area where the halo is. when a turtle does not run away it dies, I do not see how to do that.

```
breed [runners runner]
breed [halos halo]
globals [  initial-trees   ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape halos "thin ring"
  create-runners 10
    [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]

  ask runners [ set size 10 ]
  ask runners [ set color white ]

  ask patches [
    if (random 100) < density
    [ set pcolor green ]
    if pxcor = min-pxcor
    [ set pcolor red ]
  ]
  set initial-trees count patches with [pcolor = green]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask runners [ fd 0.5 ]

  walk

  if all? patches [ pcolor != red ] [ stop ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = red ] [
    ask neighbors with [ pcolor = green ] [
      let probability probability-of-spread
      let direction towards myself
      if random 100 < probability 
      [ set pcolor red
      ;if [ pcolor ] of patch xcor ycor = red [ Death ]   
      ]
    ]
    set pcolor red - 3.5    
  ]
  tick
end

to make-halo
  hatch-halos 1
  [ set size 15
    set color yellow
    __set-line-thickness 1.5 
    create-link-from myself [ tie hide-link ] 
  ]
end

to walk
  ask runners [
    rt one-of [-90 0 90]  
    forward 5                           
  ]
  tick
end
```

**Graphics elements**

```
GRAPHICS-WINDOW
286
10
796
521
-1
-1
2.0
1
10
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
-125
125
-125
125
1
1
1
ticks
30.0
BUTTON
3
10
69
43
NIL
setup
NIL
1
T
OBSERVER
NIL
NIL
NIL
NIL
1
BUTTON
4
50
71
83
NIL
go
T
1
T
OBSERVER
NIL
NIL
NIL
NIL
0
SLIDER
7
137
189
170
density
density
0.0
100.0
69.0
1.0
1
%
HORIZONTAL
MONITOR
122
25
220
70
percent burned
((count patches with [shade-of? pcolor red]) / initial-trees)\n* 100
1
1
11
SLIDER
6
182
188
215
probability-of-spread
probability-of-spread
0
100
50.0
1
1
%
HORIZONTAL
```